# Logstash filter plugin, cant import dependency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, logstash

I am having an issue with a custom filter plugin, and importing a dependency. Can anyone please help me? I get "Trying to load the X filter plugin resulted in this error: no such file to load -- memcache". The code does "require 'memcache". This is available as if I do that in any other script and run it on the CLI, it works, just not when logstash runs it? Does it use some bundled ruby or smth with a different import path?  Its 1.4.2 on Debian, if that matters. Driving me insane (Im not a ruby hacker, so im spinning my wheels a bit).

Comment: I'm dealing with the same issue right now. There doesn't seem to be anything in the documentation about how to handle plugin dependencies.

Comment: It's not something I have experienced, but an example of your logstash filter might help other to help you, I recommend you add the config to your question